# Cannot declare class App\User, because the name is already in use in my browser

Tags: database, laravel, model, eloquent

when I run the program. there something error in my model user. the path App\Models\User.php

```
 <?php

 namespace App;

 use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
 use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
 use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
 use App\Presence;
 use App\Models\Project;
 use App\Productivity;
 use App\Sick_leave;
 use App\Annual_leave;
 use App\Models\Team;

 class User extends Authenticatable
 {
   use Notifiable;

/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'password', 'level',
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];

public function presence()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Presence::class, 'astrowatch', 'user_id', 'presence_id');
    }

public function role()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Role::class, 'role_id');
    }

public function permission()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Permission::class);
    }

public function teams()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Team::class, 'user_teams');
    }
  }
```

the error is

"Cannot declare class App\User, because the name is already in use" in my browser. 
I've tried `use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\User as EloquentUser` but nothing change, still errors.

**this error**
[image: error image]

Comment: Did you try `composer dumpautoload`?

Comment: already tried `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: i had this problem and not solved by composer dump-autoload then use this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/64385832/308578

Answer (score 4):

change you `namespace`

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

 use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
 use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
 use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
 use App\Presence;
 use App\Models\Project;
 use App\Productivity;
 use App\Sick_leave;
 use App\Annual_leave;
 use App\Models\Team;

 class User extends Model implements Authenticatable
 {
   use Notifiable;

/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'password', 'level',
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];

public function presence()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Presence::class, 'astrowatch', 'user_id','presence_id');
}

public function role()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Role::class, 'role_id');
}


}
```

this will fix you namespace problem

Comment: `"Cannot declare class App\Models\User, because the name is already in use"`

Comment: do you have any other model in  your Model folder with a name User

Comment: I don`t have it

Answer (score 1):

In the new version of Laravel (version 8+) The models are kept inside a new folder namely Models inside Http.

You are getting this error because your file is inside that folder but the namespace is not leading to that folder and cannot find the required file as it is inside the folder.

Simply changing

```
namespace App;
```

to

```
namespace App\Models;
```

will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you try to change your namespace into `namespace App\Models;` to your User model?

Comment: `"Cannot declare class App\Models\User, because the name is already in use"`

Answer (score 0):

A bit late answer, but I had the same problem and solved it using `composer dump autoload`.

I had moved the models in the Models folder and the autoload file was not up to date.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code from below code in `auth.php` file

```
'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\User::class,
        ],
    ],
```